# glibc reinstallation with new kernel

Tags: kernel, configuration, glibc

Recently i removed some old kernel with autoremove function. But later found that i am getting error in configuring linux kerel. 
Also i googled and got that linux-libc-dev depends on old kernel headers which i removed.

I dont remember what version i removed.

Please guide me how can i get it back or reinstall linux-libc-dev package with my new kernel.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with 3.13.0-34 kernel and the linux-libc-dev is some 3.2.0-67 version..

I tried installing headers of linux-kernel 3.2.0-67 but its is not helping

I am getting error as

fixdep.c:(.text+0x32e): undefined reference to `__ctype_b'
fixdep.c:(.text+0x3a5): undefined reference to`__ctype_b'
fixdep.c:(.text+0x5cf): undefined reference to `__stdout'
fixdep.c:(.text+0x605): undefined reference to`__fputc_unlocked'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine i made a clean install.

The problem is i deleted a old linux-kernel used by libc-dev in an autoremove 
command.

now i locked the kernel to prevent update.

If there is any better work around please let me know